# NSString HasPrefix going wrong

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, prefix

i've problem with  nsstring hasprefix

for example. i've string like this

```
NSString *data= @"NZDIDR,NZDIDR,9571,9593,9571,IDR,2013-09-23 21:45:25.0,CUR",

if([clean hasPrefix:@"CUR"]||[clean hasPrefix:@"cur"]){
     NSLog(@"yep! there is CUR");
}
else{
   NSLog(@"no there is!");
}
```

the result should be"yep! there is CUR" right? is that error on my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean to do is check for a suffix. A prefix is at the start of the string, a suffix is at the end.

Also, your code checks for a prefix on the object `clean` not `data`.

Try:

```
if ([data hasSuffix:@"CUR"]) {
  NSLog(@"Suffix found.");
}
```